# Magnitude Spectrum from real 2D Fourier Coefficients

Tags: fourier-analysis, spectra

I know how to calculate the coefficients for a 2D Fourier Series as shown:
[2D real Fourier Series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKPQ9.png)

I calculated the Coefficients A[m][n], B[m][n], C[m][n] and D[m][n]. Now I want to create a magnitude spectrum for my discrete 2D field. How would I do that? How do I add these coefficients up or something like that, that I can plot them over the frequency –

My question is how I am able to create a magnitude spectrum from these coefficients?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I calculated the Coefficients A[m][n], B[m][n], C[m][n] and D[m][n]. Now I want to create a magnitude spectrum for my discrete 2D field. How would I do that? How do I add these coefficients up or something like that, that I can plot them over the frequency